# Is there a way to store unicode strings in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, unicode

I need to add unicode data to databases for an app I'm making. How can I do that using mongoDB in python?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747602/can-mongodb-store-and-manipulate-strings-of-utf-8-with-code-points-outside-the-b

Comment: Data in MongoDB are always stored in UTF-8. So simple answer is yes, it is even not possible to store anything different than Unicode. But you have to ensure that your python is using UTF-8 properly.